# dotdeb conflicts

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian-squeeze

I'm trying to reinstall my php but on upgrade I'm getting the following

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mysql : Conflicts: php5-mysqlnd but 5.4.9-1~dotdeb.0 is to be installed
 php5-mysqlnd : Conflicts: php5-mysql but 5.4.9-1~dotdeb.0 is to be installed
```

How to make to ignore dotdeb packages?

Comment: Can you confirm which distro you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the dotdeb packages. Add this to your sources.list.d:

```
vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list #new file

#paste these lines
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
```

Comment: I'm curious, what in the question says fefe is using debian squeeze vs some other distro?

Comment: dotdeb is for Debian, so he's using a Debian based distro. So on a hunch, it's most likely Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: hi to all I'm using debian Squeeze and latley adding to my sources the wheezy packages